# lattice of subalgebras of a finite commutative algebra

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

(I) Suppose A is a finite commutative local algebra. Must every lattice of local subalgebras of A be a distributive lattice ?

By a subalgebra of A we mean an algebra contained in A that shares the same unity element. By a lattice of subalgebras of A we mean, as usual, a family of subalgebras of A that is partially ordered with respect to set inclusion, and each of whose non-empty finite subsets admits an infimum and supremum. As usual, by a distributive lattice of subalgebras we mean a lattice L of subalgebras whose meet distributes over its join; inf(A,sup(B,C))=sup(inf(A,B),inf(A,C)).

(II) It is very well known and easy to show that every finite commutative algebra can be uniquely decomposed into a direct sum of local algebras. However, who might I accredit this to ? Who first formulated this result ? Or, what early and general theory in commutative algebra is this a direct result of in the literature ?

Comment: Aren't fields local algebras? By your definition, 
$GF(2)$, $GF(2^2)$, $GF(2^3)$, $GF(2^5)$, $GF(2^{30})$ form a sublattice of $GF(2^{30})$.   I must have misunderstood something... 

Comment: I see, by "admits a supremum" you probably mean that (a) a supremum exists in the family of all subalgebras, and (b) this sup is a member of the family. 

Comment: (II) I don't know about the history, but it immediately follows from the structure theorem of Artinian rings: Any Artinian ring is a finite direct product of local Artinian rings (Eisenbud, Cor. 2.16). 

Comment: Thank you, Ralph, for the reference. 

In response to Goldstern, yes, thank you, (a) and (b) is precisely what I meant if in (b) by "the family" it is meant the lattice L (a priori) and not necessarily the entire family of all subalgebras as in (a). 

In any case, these two axioms are basic parts of the definition of a lattice and I hope I have stated the problem clearly enough.

Comment: Perhaps, to apply said theorem of Ore, it would help to ask whether every such lattice is isomorphic to the subgroup lattice of a finite group.

Comment: In response to Woodroofe, thank you but the question is about finite local algebras. Given a unital commutative ring R, by an R-algebra it is meant, as usual, a ring A with unity for which there exists a ring homomorphism f:R->Z(R) that maps the unity of R to the unity of A, where Z(R) is the center of A. So, R need not be a field. Moreover, by a subalgebra of A it is meant a unital subring of A whose unity is the same as the unity of A. Finally, as I believe Suarez-Alvarez was pointing out, the subfield lattice of a finite field is indeed distributive.

Comment: Ok, so my prior attempt missed a condition, but the answer still seems to me like it should be "no".
Won't the group algebra of (Z_p)^2 over the field Z_p do as a counterexample?  According to Wikipedia this is a local ring.  It has at least 3 subalgebras of dimension 2 (corresponding to subgroups of order p), whose meet is Z_p, and whose join is the whole algebra.  (And this contradicts distributivity.)

Answer (score 1):

(Building on Goldstern's comment:)  If fields are ok, (and if you allow *infinite* algebras -- see comment by Mariano Suárez-Alvarez below) then the distributivity certainly does not hold.

Take e.g. a finite degree extension $F$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ with Galois group $G$.  Subalgebras of $F$ are subfields, by undergraduate field theory, so the subalgebra lattice over $\mathbb{Q}$ is the field extension lattice of $F:\mathbb{Q}$.  (I'm assuming that you're taking all your algebras over a fixed field, here $\mathbb{Q}$.)  By the Galois correspondence, the field extension lattice is anti-isomorphic to the subgroup lattice of the Galois group.

And subgroup lattices certainly need not be distributive.  Indeed, by a theorem of Ore, the subgroup lattice $L(G)$ of a finite group $G$ is distributive iff $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: The first question seems to refer to finite local algebras (and for finite fields your argument does not work because the $G$s *are* cyclic!)

Comment: Doh!  I'd missed the finite part!  I'll edit to reflect.